# Why is the rack env hash empty in Rails test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, rspec-rails

In my Rails app, I'm accessing the env hash in one of my controller actions.

Something along the lines of:

```
def my_before_filter
  env['some.key'] = "Something or other"
end
```

This works great for my requirements.

If I start my Rails app in test environment, and visit an action like:

```
# /users in UsersController#index
def index
  puts env.inspect
end
```

Then the content of the env hash is output to the console as expected.

When I get this action from within an RSPec example, the output is an empty hash?

```
it 'should get the index action' do
  get :index
end

.....{}.... # rspec output
```

Why is the env hash empty?

I've built a [dummy rails](https://github.com/Bodacious/TestEnvExample) app to show this

Comment: I think you're supposed to run it in 'development' environment.

Comment: I do normally run it in development environment. The env hash was present in development. I wanted to mention that the behaviour I see when I manually boot the server in "test" mode is not the same behaviour I see when creating a request via the test suite.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use

```
request.env
```

instead of just env within the controller code.

e.g/

```
def index
  puts request.env.inspect
end
```

Hope that helps?

BTW on another note:  when working with your github repo you need to delete the public/index.html for your root route to work, when running the server.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the feedback... this still doesn't answer why the env hash isn't available in the controller directly though?

PS - updated the repos

Comment: It's because rspec-rails bypasses the ActionController::Metal dispatch method