# What is the difference between 'env' and 'request.env' in Rails Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using `rspec` to write test for my application. In order to authorization I'm sending `token` in header:

```
request.headers['token'] = '000000099'
get :index
```

In controller side I can read this value by `request.env["HTTP_TOKEN"]` but `env["HTTP_TOKEN"]` is empty.

What is the difference between them and how can I set `env` instead of `request.env`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`request.env` is a ruby hash that contains information about a visiting user’s and server environments. `request.env` is the standard object that's being used in Rails app to extract important information such as `path_info`, `request_uri` etc.

`env` is empty for your test because `rspec-rails` bypasses the `ActionController::Metal` dispatch method.

Comment: Could you please post some example codes where and how you are using `env`?

Comment: Like this: `env["HTTP_TOKEN"]` in my controller.

Comment: So, it's just not working for your test? Otherwise it works?

Comment: `env` is empty for your test because rspec-rails bypasses the `ActionController::Metal` dispatch method. See this post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990419/why-is-the-rack-env-hash-empty-in-rails-test-environment

Comment: Ah! How did you know that? :)

Comment: `env` has been deprecated in favour of `request.env` for Rails5

Comment: Adding this comment here in case someone need: using Postman, if you need to run a POST request and set an HTTP header, create it **without** the `HTTP_` prefix. So, if you create a header named `MY_CUSTOM_HEADER` it will be available in Rails using `request.env['HTTP_MY_CUSTOM_HEADER']`