# env is empty when test from rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have one controller in which env is used:
   a = env['some_key']

then when testing using rspec, the test failed because env is empty.
I tried to change it to :
  a = request.env['some_key']
but it still failed to work. I also tried to stub it:
allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with("some_key").and_return("xxxx")

also failed.

I googled and found one post:
[What is the difference between 'env' and 'request.env' in Rails Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33195258/what-is-the-difference-between-env-and-request-env-in-rails-controller)

in that post it didn't say how to test this kind of case. Is there a efficient way to test this?

Comment: Can you share code snippets of your controller where the env is being declared, the rspec, and the failure?

Comment: `env` `request.env` and `ENV` are different things. what exactly is the intended usecase?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `stub_const` instead of `allow(...)`.

```
class Test
  attr_reader :env

  def initialize
    @env = ENV['SOME_KEY']
  end
end

describe Test do
  subject(:test) { Test.new }

  before { stub_const('ENV', {'SOME_KEY' => 'mock'}) }

  it 'displays the correct environment variable' do
    expect(test.env).to eq('mock')
  end
end
```